# Function to clean image names for Packer's Azure builder

Tags: azure, packer

When building packer images for AWS there is a function called `clean_ami_name` which gets rid of invalid characters.  For google there's another called `clean_image_name` for google cloud.

Is there an equivalent for Azure, or do people always hard-code image names in the `managed_image_name` string?

Relevant docs are [here](https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/engine.html) which mention AWS and GCP but not Azure, I expect this is a super common need for azure image building.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such function. Please submit a [feature request](https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/new).

Comment: Done.  Not the answer I was hoping for, but I expected this was the correct one.  https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/6552

Answer (score 1):

There is no implemented function like this at the moment . But Hope is on the way: https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/pull/6558

Answer (score 0):

You can use **clean_resource_name** function. This function will replace illegal characters with a "-" character. Example:

`"mybuild-{{isotime | clean_resource_name}}"` will become **mybuild-2017-10-18t02-06-30z**.

Note: Valid Azure image names must match the regex ^[^*\W][\w-.*)]{0,79}$

https://www.packer.io/docs/templates/engine#clean_resource_name-3